# How to use BufferedReader before PrintWriter in Java

Tags: java

I am working on small Server/ Client application (console base) in Java. The purpose of the application is to send number from client to server and in the server add (+1) with it and return back to client. Client print the line and send back to server the increased number until it reaches 10.

The connectivity between both classes is working properly, but when I put `BufferedReader` before `PrintWriter` in server class, then the application doesn't work and also doesn't throws any error.

**Client Code:**

```
int count = 1;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;

Socket socket = null;

try {
    socket = new Socket("localhost",3700);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());    
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(in.read() != 10){
    out.println(count);
    out.flush();
    System.out.print(in.read());
};

out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

**Server Code:**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket socket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
int count = 1;

try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3700);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.println(count);
out.flush();

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while(in.read() != 10){
    count = in.read();
    count++;
};

in.close();
out.close();

serverSocket.close();
socket.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(in.read() != 10){
    count = in.read();
    count++;
};
```

You are reading characters and throwing them away, and you are ignoring end of stream. It should be:

```
int ch;
while((ch = in.read()) !- -1 && ch != 10){
    count = ch;
    count++;
};
```

and similarly for the server side. The -1 test is the end of stream condition, which happens when the peer closes the connection.

But more probably you should be using `readLine()` and `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    int value = Integer.parseInt(line);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. But it prints only one line the end result which is 10. I used `System.out.println(in.read());` in the while but still gets only one line. Do I need to use while loop in Server side? Or shall I ignore it?

Comment: That's because you're reading another character, in exactly the way I just told you not to. It should be `System.out.println(ch);`. And what part of 'and similarly for the server side' didn't you understand?